# Open source proxy server SSL interception and HTTP header insertion

Tags: proxy, linux-networking, open-source

I am new to proxies. Can anyone suggest an open source proxy server that supports SSL interception and HTTP header insertion.

Answer (score 1):

Good day and well met, fine sir of the fair internets! Might I humbly suggest to thee that thou mightest be piqued at the project known among the gentry as [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org). I do say that it appears to have all the features you need, natheless I have no personal experience with all thy needs.

Enjoy this fine dandy, soothfast you will be sated with it. Fare thee well, good doctor master and may we fain meet again some fine day.

Comment: Have you been drinking again @WesleyDavid? :)